# How to display 11 variables of descriptive statistic on the same line

Tags: python

I'm trying to display the Descriptive statistic of a data frame with 12 variables.For readability my goal is to have all the variables on the same line.The following is my code

```
# Descriptive statistic

from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import set_option
filename = 'winequality-red.csv'
data = read_csv(filename,sep = ';')
set_option('display.max_columns',500)
descriptions = data.describe()
print(descriptions)
```

the output is giving me 2 lines for the variables
Please I need help to achieve my goal
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of you are using **IDE**, or **notebook**, it's going to **hurt** the readability, and never help.

Anyway, it's could be done by using **transpose** `descriptions.T`.

If you are using **IDE** you could use `IPython.display` instead of `print`

```
from IPython.display import display
display(descriptions) # OR - display(descriptions.T)
```